# Warning find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument

Tags: shell, find

I have this bash command:

```
FILES=$(find $(dirname "$DIR")/**/**/*.js -type f -maxdepth 8 -not -path "*/babel/*" -not -path "*/examples/*");
```

I get this warning:

> find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a
>   non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth
>   affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after
>   it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Anyone know what that's about? Google yield nothing. If there is anything else dubious about my command please lmk!

Comment: I don't think I am using the globs and maxdepth correctly, probably should use one or the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you read the message it tells you that you have used `-maxdepth` after `-type`. The point is that `-maxdepth` is a global option (others include `-xdev` to avoid searches crossing mount points and `-noleaf` which stops find assuming that directories have standard unix link counts) and `-type` is part of an expression.

If you swap the order of `-type f` and `-maxdepth 8` the message will go away.