# Listing files with given characters in their name

Tags: linux, ls

I want to list all the files, in directory I am currently in, with for example "a" in their name. I know that the first part of the command would be `ls -l`, but i do not know how to finish it.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203046/100397

Comment: Well, I went on a quest - to find out why the 'no no no'. And, I learned you shouldn't process the output of 'ls' for a couple of reasons. Thanks to @roaima, I learned something new! Now, to be honest (for my simple needs), I'd probably still us `ls | grep a` but that's 'cause I'm inherently lazy. Definitely don't do that. If you want to learn why you shouldn't parse 'ls' then click [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). And now I know!

Comment: @KGIII great to hear you've expanded your skillset; I love doing that too. It's more than this, though; for names you can just use wildcards, so `ls -d *a*` to match file names containing `a` (use `man ls` to find out about `-d`)

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on glob wildcards, including `*` and `?`.

- `*` matches zero or more characters
- `?` matches exactly one character
- `[...]` matches one of a set of characters (eg `[abc]` matches any of `a`, `b`, `c`)

So to find all file names containing `abc` you simply use the glob `*abc*`. This can be used anywhere you want this list:

```
ls *abc*
rm -i *abc*
echo *abc*
```

A note of warning, though, to say that the command line gets run *after* the expansion. (It's the shell performing the expansion, not the command.) So if you had a filename like `-abc`, the expansion of `ls *abc` will result in `ls -abc`, which will result in `ls` parsing the set of flags `-labc` with no filename argument. Fix this by prefixing wildcard expansions with `./` to force an explicit path to the current directory

```
ls ./*abc*
rm -i ./*abc*
echo ./*abc*
```

Note that for `ls`, if any of the arguments is a directory, the *contents* of that directory will be listed instead of the directory name itself. Fix that with the `-d` flag, and while you're there use `-q` if your version of `ls` supports it,

```
ls -dq ./*abc*
```